# How to display placelikelihood on map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

```
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);


// Use the builder to create a FindCurrentPlaceRequest.

    FindCurrentPlaceRequest request =
            FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeFields);

// Call findCurrentPlace and handle the response (first check that the user has granted permission).

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> placeResponse = placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request);
        placeResponse.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                FindCurrentPlaceResponse response = task.getResult();
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : response.getPlaceLikelihoods()) {

                    Log.i("TAG", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %f",
                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                }
            } else {
                Exception exception = task.getException();
                if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
                }
            }
        });
    } else {

        // A local method to request required permissions;
        // See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

        Log.i("TAG", "Turn on location on your device!");
    }
```

I want to display all these places on the map using a marker or anything alternatively existing:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLoc).title("Marker in Birmingham"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the lat/lng you get as a variable, e.g.:

`latLng = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng()`

Then pass it into a marker as follows:

`mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng))`

Resources:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place#get-current

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker#add_a_map

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx for help, kinda worked. I actually needed not just likelihood places. I wanted to find nearby places by specific name within a specific radius, but the new Places SDK for android won't let me do that.

Comment: Could you suggest anything that will help/

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)

Comment: The Places SDK for Android does not have a nearby search service. You'll need to use the web service / java client, but note that the API key used for Nearby Search or other web services will not be secured and you'd need to implement other security techniques such as setting up a proxy server.

Comment: Check out these links: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java and https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table_sup_5

Comment: There's also a FR in Google's issue tracker to add Nearby Search to Places SDK for Android https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133276015

Comment: I tried that one from github however I cannot understand it fully. Its docs are dry for me. Do you know any resources with proper examples? Or maybe some youtube videos. I need this for my dissertation project. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206872/discussion-between-marin-and-evan).

Comment: I don't but I can implement this myself and then show you my code so that you can use it for guidance. I can see you have already created a question for this so i will answer you in that thread once i have working code. But probably will do this tomorrow because i'm too tired now haha.

Comment: I will highly appreciate that. I really need help! Cheers